# What are the differences between differential and gradient?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

As far as i know, both differential and gradient are vectors where their dot product with a unit vector give directional derivative with the direction of the unit vector. So what are the differences?

Answer (score 20):

There is hardly a noticable difference when you work on Euclidean spaces. You can think of the differential at a point as being a linear map, which maps a vector to the dot product of the vector with the gradient. The differential generalizes in a natural way to more abstract settings, such as functions on a manifold. The gradient has no such generalization, unless the manifold is equipped with a metric (which is a fancy way of saying there is a dot product defined for any two tangent vectors based at the same point).

I could go on, but I am afraid this would turn into a lecture on differential geometry.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I came here by studying differential geometry, in fact, and I'm intrigued. Does the gradient always generalize to the differential, or does this depend on the metric, or something else ?

Comment: @TristanDuquesne I helps to know the difference between the tangent space and the cotangent space (more generally: the difference between a vector space and its dual). The differential of a function is an element of the cotangent, while the gradient is an element of the tangent space. The differential is always defined, while we can only talk about the gradient if we have a map that transforms covectors into vectors. A dot product provides such a map. So yes: the gradient depends on the metric.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up !

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, and in an informal sense, it is the difference between the projection of the gradient onto the plane below the surface (this is the normal "gradient"), and a "risen" gradient which is embedded in the 3D surface.

**Note**: Technically, the differential and gradient reduce to the same thing in the case of the map from $R^2\rightarrow R $. That is, they are both row vectors consisting of the partial derivatives of f.

However, as the differential is used in higher dimensional cases usually, being a generalization of the 1D gradient described above, one might informally interpret "the differential of f" as the result of converting f into the surface it implicitly represents using some map **x**, and taking the differential of **x** (a map from a plane to a surface).

What is the difference between the two, then, if we take this informal interpretation of "differential of f"?

I will explain:

Examine what happens when we map the gradient vector of f using the differential of **x**: The 2D gradient vector $(u_x,u_y)$ becomes $(1,1,u_x+u_y)$, i.e. it "rises" and becomes embedded 3 dimensionally in the surface, whereas before it was only a projection on the plane beneath the surface. Note that this 3D vector is the analog to the "amount of change" in the gradient direction $||\nabla f||$, a scalar, in the 1D case, and is the result of taking the differential of **x** at a point p=(u,v) in the direction of the gradient of f.

Technically, the differential itself (at the point) is the matrix operator which implemented this transformation, just as in the 1D case of f the gradient was the vector which dotted with the direction gave the amount of change in that direction.