# Gradient of $||Ax - y||^2$ with respect to $A$

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

How do I proceed to find $\nabla_A||Ax - y||^2$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and the norm is the Euclidean norm.

**Attempt so far**

$$||Ax - y||^2 = (Ax-y)^T(Ax-y) = x^TA^TAx - 2x^TAy + y^Ty  $$

$$ \nabla_A(x^TAy) = xy^T$$

**Where I am stuck**

I don't know how to tackle the $x^TA^TAx$ term since if I try to apply chain rule, I will have to differentiate a matrix with respect to a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Before we start deriving the gradient, some facts and notations for brevity:

- Trace and Frobenius product relation $$\left\langle A, B C\right\rangle={\rm tr}(A^TBC) := A : B C$$
- Cyclic properties of Trace/Frobenius product 
  \begin{align}
  A : B C 
   &= BC : A \\
   &= A C^T   :  B  \\
   &= {\text{etc.}} \cr
  \end{align}

Let $f := \left\|Ax-y \right\|^2 = Ax-y:Ax-y$.

Now, we can obtain the differential first, and then the gradient.
\begin{align}
df  
&= d\left( Ax-y:Ax-y \right) \\
&= \left(dA \ x : Ax-y\right)  + \left(Ax-y : dA \ x\right) \\
&= 2 \left(Ax - y\right)  : dA \ x \\
&= 2\left( Ax-y\right)x^T : dA\\
\end{align}

Thus, the gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial A} \left( \left\|Ax-y \right\|^2 \right)= 2\left( Ax-y\right)x^T.
\end{align}

Comment: What is the difference between differential and gradient?

Comment: see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289923/what-are-the-differences-between-differential-and-gradient

Answer (score 0):

For matrices, the most easy way is often to get back to definition of differentiability, i.e. :

$$||(A+H)x - y||^2-||Ax - y||^2=L_A(H) + o(\|H\|)$$

With $L_A$ a linear map.

We begin with :
$$||(A+H)x - y||^2=\langle Ax+Hx-y , Ax+Hx-y \rangle.$$

Then we have :

$$||(A+H)x - y||^2= \langle Ax-y,Ax-y\rangle + 2\langle Hx,Ax -y\rangle + \langle Hx,Hx\rangle.$$

To conclude : $$||(A+H)x - y||^2-||Ax - y||^2=2\langle Hx,Ax -y\rangle + o (\|H\|)$$

Thus :

$$\left(\nabla_A||Ax - y||^2\right)_{i,j}=2\langle E_{i,j}x,Ax -y\rangle$$

With $E_{i,j}$ the matrix with a $1$ at row $i$ and column $j$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Why is the final answer a number and not a matrix?

Comment: Because I misunderstood the notation and went a bit fast at the end. Is it better now ?