# An intuitive difference between differentials, gradients and one forms?

Tags: vector-analysis

In this [article](http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node22.html) , they write $$ df = f_x dx + f_y dy$$ and call it the 'differential of f' but what is a differental actually?

I know the directional directive is,

$$ D_{v} f = \nabla F \cdot v$$

And the gradient is $ \nabla F$ but what exactly is this mysterious differential quantity? Is it a one form? because I don't understand enough differential geometery to get that. But, I've seen this 'differential' idea used everywhere , especially in 'thermodynamics'. I have seen [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289923/what-are-the-differences-between-differential-and-gradient) on mathestack exchange, however, I feel like I didn't understand anything after reading it. So, I'm looking for simpler explanations with more concrete examples.

Comment: This is the *total* derivative or *total* differential.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a 1-form. I'll offer a brief explanation here, but first let me suggest a couple of textbooks for a more leisurely treatment. First we have *Gravitation* by Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler, Part III, especially section 9.4. Don't be put off by this being a text on General Relativity; you also don't need to read the earlier sections. MTW (as it's often called) spill a lot of ink trying to give geometrical intuition.

Another good book: *Applied Differential Geometry* by William Burke.

OK, *formally* a 1-form is a smooth field of cotangent vectors, and a cotangent vector is a linear function on the space of tangent vectors. Let's unwrap that with a concrete example. Consider the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, the square of the distance from the origin. Pick a point in the plane, say at $P=(a,b)$. A tangent vector at $P$ is just a vector that we picture anchored at $P$. So think of an arrow going from $(a,b)$ to $(a+h,b+k)$. Let's say $v=(h,k)$. The coordinates of the tangent vector are just $(h,k)$, since the space of all tangent vectors at $P$ all have the same $(a,b)$.

Now we ask, how quickly is $f$ increasing in direction $v$? As you know, the answer is $D_v f = \nabla f\cdot v = f_x h+ f_y k$, which is $2ah+2bk$ here. That's a linear function of the tangent vector $(h,k)$. Such a linear function is called a cotangent vector.

We have a cotangent vector at every point in the plane, or in other words, a field of cotangent vectors. The cotangent vectors depend smoothly on the point $P$, since the coefficients $2a$ and $2b$ are smooth functions of its coordinates $(a,b)$. So that's the 1-form $df$.

MTW recommends picturing the 1-form by thinking about "infinitesimal" tangent vectors and how they cross level curves. Take an "infinitesimal" neighborhood of $P$, and blow it up by looking at it with a microscope set to "infinite" magnification. Look at all the level curves of $f$. They will look like a bunch of parallel lines, because of the whole infinitesimal thing. (This is just a fanciful way of talking about limits and linear approximations.) The signed number of parallel lines crossed by an infinitesimal vector $v$ tells you the directional derivative. That's a linear function of $v$. So a 1-form at a point can be pictured as a bunch of closely-spaced parallel lines. The more closely spaced, the bigger the value of the 1-form.

There's a lot more to say, both formally and intuitively, but I'll leave that to the books. (Also, their diagrams are invaluable.)

Comment: the directional derivative gives a scalar, so I don't get why you are calling it a vector by any means..

Comment: $D_vf$ is a scalar, for a particular $f$ and $v$. Now keep $f$ fixed but let $v$ vary. Then $v\mapsto D_vf$ is linear function of $v$. Now, $v$ belongs to a vector space (the so-called tangent space at $P$, denoted $T_P$). The collection of scalar-valued linear functions with domain $T_P$ is the dual space of $T_P$, and is called the cotangent space at $P$. Its elements are called cotangent vectors. (I should add all this to my answer, but I have to figure out how to phrase it.)

Comment: so the cotangent space is not intrinsic to vector space but rather a property how the function we are using

Comment: The cotangent space is a vector space. That is, it satisfies the formal definition of what a vector space.is (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space). It's true that its elements don't look like arrows. Given any vector space $V$, there is a so-called dual space $V^*$, which is also a vector space. The cotangent space is the dual space of the tangent space, whose elements do "look like arrows".

Comment: Nice exposition. In the context of differential geometry, it seems to be useful to mention that the differential of a map between manifolds at some prescribed point, is a linear map between the corresponding tangent spaces. And if 'manifolds' is intimidating, this can be illustrated quite clearly in the plane, using curves, without mentioning manifolds at all.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, the word 'differential' can be treated as *a small change in $f$ based on linear interpolation*.

As an example, consider $f(x,y)$ be the height of a certain hill at $(x,y)$. If we want to estimate the change in height in between $(1,1)$ and $(1.01,0.98)$, then we can apply the formula of differential and write
$$ df = f_x(1,1) (1.01-1) + f_y(1,1) (0.98 - 1).$$
Of course, this differential is also a 1-form (it should be no surprise it is so), but it shall not be further elaborated here as it is not directly related to your context.